# XNA UnitCircle convert to Radians

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, rotation

I am doing a 2D (from above) game in XNA, but this is more of a math problem.
I am trying to rotate the sprite in the same direction as the direction I push the stick on the Xbox controller.

You see If I pull my stick in a direction I also want my character to face the same way. The Xbox controller gives me cordinates like in the UnitCircle, a X and Y value with the value +1 to -1 and 0 is standard position. And I need the angle in Radians to use it in XNA, please help me with this, I don't know how to convert from Unit Circle to Radians.

I found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix but it was very hard to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge disclaimer:  I'm working with ancient and forgotten trig, so please forgive me if I put you wrong!

First up, have a think about what the unit circle information is telling you.  It looks something like this:

[image: Unit circle]

The orange (x,y) coordinates are telling you in which direction the controller has been moved.

The information tells you the height of the triangle, and the base of the triangle.

What you want to know is the angle at the tip of the triangle that touches the centre.

Another way of looking at our orange triangle is like this.

[image: Triangle]

You want to know the angle in green, and you know the adjacent side (which is your x co-ordinate) and the opposite site (which is your y co-ordinate). A little SOHCAHTOA, and you can see that

tan(θ) = y / x

which we can solve with

θ = (inverse tan) (y/x)

It looks like C# uses radians in tan and atan.

I'd suggest spending some time here: http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html to help get your head around some of these concepts.

Comment: (I hope this helps - have to dash off but will check again once I'm home).